# How to give current directory as Path name while reading an Excel file?

Tags: perl, excel

I am trying to update an already existing Excel file "Test.xls"  Now, instead of giving the complete path of the Test.xls file, I wish to know how to read the Test.xls file from current directory. I am using Eclipse in Windows environment. Below is my code:

```
my $Excel = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Excel.Application')
|| Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application', 'Quit');  

my $Book = $Excel->Workbooks->Open("Test.xls"); #This line throws an error but works if I give complete path name as D:/eclipse/workspace/testing/Test.xls

my $Sheet = $Book->Worksheets(1);

foreach my $data (@ifrules)
{
 $Sheet->Cells($row,$col)->{'Value'} =$data;
 $row++;
}

$Book->Close;
```

I have tried various options like *./Test.xls, .\Test.xls* and others too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I found, you can use `getcwd()` to get the current working directory.  You can then concatenate that with the name of the file within `$Excel->Workbooks->Open()` to give the current directory plus the name of the file.

[Source Link](http://perldoc.perl.org/Cwd.html)

*Explanation:* The basic issue here is that you are passing the file name to Excel, which doesn't know about Perl's current working directory.  That is why you have to find out the full path name and give it to `$Excel->Workbooks->Open()`.